# Стили Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, style

Здравствуйте.
Для экономии время могу наполнить стили основными характеристиками? Ширина, высота, отступы и поля(margin), размер шрифта, цвет, и так далее. После чего присваивать элементам нужный стиль.

```
<resourse>
 <style name="Big_letter">
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
  <item name="android:TextSize">55sp</<item>
 </style>
 <style name="Small_letter>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
  <item name="android:TextSize">35sp</<item>
 </style>
</resourse>







   <Button
     style="Big_letter"
     android:text="Big"
     android:id="@+id/btn_big"/>

   <Button
     style="Small_letter"
     android:text="Small"
     android:id="@+id/btn_sml"/>



Я пробывал так сделать, приложение "выбивает" хотя студия не подчёркивает красным.
 Спасибо.
```

Comment: Приложите вывод ошибки в логах. А так пока видно что вы в атрибуте оппечатались: `android:TextSize`. Должно быть так: `android:textSize`

Comment: да, исправил ,  работает. В логах жаловалось на строку в  Java  коде, на первый взгляд ни как не связанной с проблемой стиля .

Comment: Вот на эту :       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Я так и не понял есть ли у вас какая-то проблема и если есть то где и какая.

Comment: Проблемы нет, вопрос состоял в том возможно ли это осуществит в принципе. Спасибо за ваше внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это возможно. Единоразовое определение характеристик (маргины падинги, шрифты и т.д.) и последующее подключение их к нужному элементу здорово будет экономить мне время.